# Find a specific field in a document, limit 5, and order by ascending distance from a gps location

Tags: mongodb

I have a `location` collection, and have used this code that shows location near the assigned geo location below:

`db.location.find({ll:{$near:[-80.12996, 25.79315]}}).limit(5).pretty()`

However, now I need to expand from this and find the top 5 pizza restaurant (field is type: "Pizza"), and ordered by the `geo` location above (need to use near to have it by ascending). Can't figure out how to do it. I tried to use `aggregate` but not working for me, I might have it in the wrong order or something.

Comment: Did you set index for text field ? If you want to search by text you need to set index first, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/link-text-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:** create an index of the field with have location.

```
db.location.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere"  } )
```

**step 2:** try this query replacing your coordinates in lat lng:

```
db.location.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat, lng]},
                    maxDistance:1000,
                    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                    spherical: true
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    type: "Pizza",
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    'dist.calculated': 1
                }
            },
            {
                $limit : 5
            }
        ])
```